# Wronskian, differentials equations

Tags: differential-equations

How can I in *Mathematica* find the `Wronskian` for two piecewise functions

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi_1(x) &=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
-x^3 & x \in [-1,0], \\
0 & x \in (0,1].
\end{array}
\right. \\
\varphi_2(x) &=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
0 & x \in [-1,0], \\
-x^3 & x\in (0,1].
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The question might need rephrasing.

Comment: Question is how i can for $\varphi_1(x),\varphi_2(x)$ find Wronskian in Mathematica . ?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

> Question is how i can for φ1(x),φ2(x) find Wronskian in Mathematica

I assume you do not want to use `Wronskian` build in for some reason?

One way could be to implement W from the definition?

```
y1[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x^3, -1 < x < 0}, {0, True}}];
y2[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x^3, 0 < x < 1}, {0, True}}];    
wronskian[y1_, y2_, x_] := Det[{{y1, y2}, {D[y1, x], D[y2, x]}}];
```

And now

```
wronskian[y1[x], y2[x], x] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For example,

```
  wronskian[9 Cos[2 x], 2 Cos[x]^2 - 2 Sin[x]^2, x] // Simplify
  (*0*)
```

Check:

```
  Wronskian[{9 Cos[2 x], 2 Cos[x]^2 - 2 Sin[x]^2}, x]
  (*0*)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for `Wronksian[]`:

> The Wronskian determinant is defined as `Det[Table[D[Subscript[y, i],{x,j}],{i,m},{j,0,m-1}]]`.

The statement was not exactly correct:

```
Det[Table[D[{y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, j}], {j, 0, 2 - 1}]] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Wronskian[{y1[x], y2[x]}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An equivalent approach to `Table`:

```
ClearAll[wronskian];
wronskian[v_?VectorQ, x_Symbol] := Det@NestList[D[#, x] &, v, Length@v - 1]

wronskian[{y1[x], y2[x]}, x] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I still like `UnitStep`.

```
ψ1[x_] = -x^3 (1 - UnitStep[x]);
ψ2[x_] = -x^3 (1 - UnitStep[-x]);
```

It is obvious that the slope of both of these functions is `0` at `x = 0`

```
ψ1p[x_] = ψ1'[x] /. {(D[ψ1[x], x] /. x -> 0) -> 0}
(*-3 x^2 (1 - UnitStep[x])*)

ψ2p[x_] = ψ2'[x] /. {(D[ψ2[x], x] /. x -> 0) -> 0}
```

And the Wronskian

```
wr = ψ1p[x_] ψ2[x] - ψ2p[x_] ψ1[x]
(*0*)
```