# Find the Jacobian and Wronskian of 3x3 system

Tags: programming

Can you help me find the code that calculates the matrix Jacobian and Wronskian of 3x3 type. A matrix with the help of the "modlye" commend. I can only write this:

```
Wronskian[{Exp[x], Exp[2 x]}, x]
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/how-to-make-jacobian-automatically-in-mathematica, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187014/wronskian-differentials-equations

Comment: Can you give an example of "3x3 type" you're interested in? It's not clear to me what you're starting from. Since you give a 2x2 Wronskian, I assume you'd know how to do this 3x3 one, `Wronskian[{Exp[x], Exp[2 x], Exp[3 x]}, x]`.  Is "3x3 type" is something else?

Comment: `D[{f1[x1, x2, x3], f2[x1, x2, x3], f3[x1, x2, x3]}, {{x1, x2, x3}}]`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I mean, I'm trying to get the Jacobian and Wronskian matrix of any 3x3 type matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The `Wronskian` is built in. And the Jacobian you may e.g. define by:

```
jacobian[f : {f1_, f2_, f3_}, x : {x1_, x2_, x3_}] := Function[
    t, {Derivative[1, 0, 0][#] @@ t, Derivative[0, 1, 0][#] @@ t, 
       Derivative[0, 0, 1][#] @@ t} & /@ f][x]
jacobian[{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}]
```

[image]

where f1,f2,f3, are 3 functions of 3 variables and x is a 3 vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So can we apply this working system for the wronskian matrix? I tried but failed

Comment: The wronskian can be written like: `Wronskian[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, x]` , where f1[x],.. are functions of x. If you have problems with this, post your code.